Plotting Higher Timeframe Adaptive EMA on Lower Timeframe
In the below code, i am having a function declared for adaptive ema which i am using to plot the adaptive ema on lower timeframe which avoids repainting. It plots the adaptive ema but i am finding difference in values of ema.for example if higher timeframe is daily and lowe timeframe is 15 min: when i am plotting the adaptive ema of daily timeframe on 15 min timeframe using request.security function and when i am plotting the adaptive ema on daily timeframe itself using the adaptive ema function, i found there is difference in values. can someone help to correct the issue in below code.
reshtf = input.timeframe(title="HTF Timeframe", defval="1D",inline="HTF",group = "Timeframe")
htflinewidth = input.int(5,title="HTFLineWidth",minval = 1,inline="HTF",group = "Timeframe")

_atr_adapt_ema(src, len)=>
    atr = ta.atr(len)
    atr /= len
    atrMax = ta.highest(atr, len)           
    atrMin = ta.lowest(atr, len)     
    coeff = atrMin != atrMax ? 1 - (atr - atrMin) / (atrMax - atrMin) : 0.5
    alpha = 2.0 / (1 + len * (coeff + 1.0) / 2.0)
    emaout = 0.0
    emaout := nz(emaout[1]) + alpha * (src - nz(emaout[1]))
    emaout

Shortema = _atr_adapt_ema(close, 2)
Longema = _atr_adapt_ema(close, 7)
htf_ema (_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 :        0],gaps = barmerge.gaps_off,lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
htfShortema = htf_ema (syminfo.tickerid, reshtf,Shortema)
htfLongema = htf_ema (syminfo.tickerid, reshtf,Longema)


i tried using the request security function with or without gaps and lookahead function on and off but giving different results only
